# Java - Dynamic JSON creation with selected option

Tags: java, json, dynamic

I need to prepare JSON object like below, based on the user selected option dynamically. What is best approach to dynamically set value of "selected" key in JAVA. I have if-else and Switch in my mind but I am looking for better approach.

```
[{
        "name": "By Distance",
        "selected": "FALSE"
    },
    {
        "name": "By Rating",
        "selected": "TRUE"
    },
    {
        "name": "By Cost",
        "selected": "FALSE"
    }
]
```

Comment: You have a list of json objects, you can loop over it and filter what you need. Or if there are a great many number of records then consider streaming it.

Comment: I don't have list of objects ready, I need to prepare the list with the selected option.

Comment: Do elaborate on how you'd get the, what would be your input?

Comment: Can't you just add an object with the `name` attribute to the array only if it's selected? Is the not selected information relevant? You could use a `List<String> selectedInput` and check selection by `selectedInput.contains(aStrNameValue)`. Sending it via WS would result in something like `['By Distance', 'By Cost']` showing only selected inputs.

Comment: What do you use in your front end? What is the structure of html and js?